# Purging cassandra column family

Tags: cassandra

I have a column family whose definition is as follows :

---

`create column family Message with  key_validation_class ='UTF8Type' and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'`

---

Whose row key is a unique id and two columns are stored in a row

1. message : a string message
2. created_dt : the date time when this row was created in cassandra

Now my requirement is to move and delete all messages that are there since more than a year. I do not want to completely delete that data, rather move it from the working cassandra cluster to another one , which is used for archival.

Are there any tools/scripts that can help achieving this?

If I have to write code using hector then how can this be done efficiently ? How do I figure out the keys that have the created_dt < current_dt - 1 year ?

Comment: Can you tell what is the column validator class used for this column family ?

Comment: @doanduyhai I did not thought of defining that. But now I'll define the columns also , i.e. will make it a static column family. For message and created_dt the validator classes would be UTF8Type and DateType respectively.

Comment: In Cassandra, A column can also have an optional expiration date called TTL (time to live) ;TTL columns are marked as deleted (with a tombstone) after the requested amount of time has expired. FOR more info go through "Setting an expiring column" in Cassandra documentation .

Comment: Cassandra's documentation about [backup and restore](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/backup_restore) looks the way to go. But I want to delete the data from the working cluster but not from the archival one. If I take snapshots or incrementals then in that case, data that gets deleted from the working shall also get deleted from the archival cluster.  How should I avoid this while still using the backup and restore support provided by cassandra.

Comment: Found Netflix's [priam](https://github.com/Netflix/Priam/wiki/Backups)     useful which allows incremental backups.